# Update content in child window from another child window

Tags: jquery, window.opener

I want to do something that I thought would be relatively easy - hopefully someone knows how to do this. I have a window that has links on it that create multiple children windows. What I'd like to do is update the content of a child window from a different child window --

From child 1:

change content of parent.child2.div

I hope that makes sense... I've searched and searched, but can't vfigure out how to make this work with windows (not just div's or span's, etc).

TIA!

Example Parent:

```
var win1,win2;
function openwin1(){
    if(win1 == undefined)
        win1 = window.open('/win1.html','win1');
    else
        win1.focus();
}

function openwin2(){
    if(win2 == undefined)
        win2 = window.open('/win2.html','win2');
    else
        win2.focus();
}

$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('#win1link').click(function() {
        openwin1()
    }); 
    $('#win2link').click(function() {
        openwin2()
    });

});

<p><A HREF="javascript: void(0);" ID="win1link">Win 1</A></p>
<p><A HREF="javascript: void(0);" ID="win2link">Win 2</A></p>
```

from win1 I would like to update a div in win2:

Example win1:

```
function updateParentChild () {
    parentwindow.win2.div.html('newhtml');
}
```

Example win2:

```
<DIV>oldhtml</DIV>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of your HTML so we can see the elements and how you're trying to get them to interact?

Comment: I added some code above - please let me know if that is enough to explain what I am trying to do ...

Comment: So you're trying to do something other than open new windows when the `<a>` elements are clicked? Are you saying you want to asynchronously load the content of win1.html or win2.html into an element on the parent page? By the way, there's an error in your second `<p>` element ID (it's "win12ink")

Comment: The parent window opens the two children windows. Then from inside win1 I would like to update the contents of a div in win2

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do something like this (code is for illustration only)

win1.html

```
<input type="text" onKeyUp="window.opener.win2.document.getElementById('my_div').innerHTML = this.value;" />
```

win2.html

```
<div id="my_div"></div>
```

Everything needs to be on the same domain, Chrome might not work on local files.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This did the trick!! I figured there had to be a simple solution! One last question - I am trying to focus on win2 after I update it - but it's not working in FF - any idea? tried: $(window.opener.win2).focus(); and window.opener.win2.focus(); but neither works ...

Comment: The window.opener.win2.focus() should work but that will depend on the user settings and if the windows were opened in tabs or new windows, etc... You can find more details here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_focus.asp